# COUNTIF formula - Counting number of occurrences a particular time occurs between two time intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a COUNTIF forumla to determine:

1. If a particular time (**Sheet 1 Col B** as pictured) occurs between any of the time intervals in **Sheet 2 ColF&G**
2. Do a count of how many instances that fall within each time range (**Sheet 2 ColF&G**) reading from **Sheet 1 Col B**

The goal is that there is a target value count for each time interval (**Sheet 2 Col H**) and I want to see if the target is met each time or not through conditional formatting.

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

I have written a similar piece of VBA code to determine if the time falls within the time intervals, but goal is to automatically update with a formula rather than running a macro for it. Any help would be appreciated.

**VBA code (using an array) as below incase anyone finds it useful:**

```
Dim Start As Variant, fin As Variant,Test As Variant, xa As Long, y1 As Long, Z1 As Long, k1 As Long: k1 = 2

Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:A" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
fin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2:C" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
Test = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Range("J2:J" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2

       isFound = False
        For xa = LBound(Test) To UBound(Test)
            For y1 = LBound(Start) To UBound(Start)
                For Z1 = LBound(fin) To UBound(fin)

            If Test(xa, 1) >= Start(y1, 1) And Test(xa, 1) <= fin(Z1, 1) Then

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(k1, 12) = fin(Z1, 2)

                k1 = k1 + 1

            isFound = True

            End If
                y1 = y1 + 1

            Next
        Next
        If Not isFound Then

        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add an additional column with a time fraction of the 'Input date / time' column, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:$C$6>E2),--($C$2:$C$6<F2))
```

Formula for getting time part (in C column in example)

```
=TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2), SECOND(B2))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Basic thanks very much for the answer! Just before I accept it, I think the semi-colons should be replaced with commas (well for my 2016 excel version I had to change the above answers). Other than it works as required. Thanks again!

Comment: @bewislammeld semi colons being changed for commas is **not** an error, this is just due to regional settings that differ on computers. Something that we usually accept on here.

Comment: I figured there might have been a reason for it - good to know for future references - I accepted the answer above anyhow :)